# Reading a text file and converting into variable

Tags: c++

I have this entry, for example:

```
TIE-Fighter (v=250, a=75, s=30, c=45)
```

And this is my code:

```
  typedef struct {
         string type;  
         int velocity;
         int attack;    
         int shield;    
         int cost;      
    } Fighter;


int main(){
  string nomFichero;
  cout << "Filename:" << endl; 
  cin >> nomFichero;
  ifstream fich(nomFichero.c_str());
  if (fich.is_open()){
    string s;
    Fighter f;
    while(fich>>f.type){
        fich >> f.velocity;
        fich >> f.attack;
        fich >> f.shield;
        fich >> f.cost;

    }
    // cout f.type,f.attack etc...   
    fich.close();
  }

}
```

But it doesn't work... Output's something like this:

```
TIE-Fighter (v=0, a=32708, s=1963230416, c=32708)
```

So how can I read a text file and separate them into that variables?

Comment: Does the file have to be formatted like `TIE-Fighter (v=250, a=75, s=30, c=45)`?  You can save yourself a lot of time, pain and effort if you have the data in the file stored like `TIE-Fighter 250 75 30 45`

Comment: It has to be like that... It's homework :( and because I have to export and import, so has to be the same format.

Comment: load the line into a string and parse it. no short cut here.

Comment: @Seokjin Then you have to consider parsing the stuff in the file and check which value should be read.

Comment: This could be set up this way to be a challenge, but the lesson learned is almost exactly how NOT to do this. Sticking with the library, read a line with `std::getline`. Pop the line into a `std::stringstream`. Parse the `std::stringstream` on comma with `std::getline`. put each token into another `std::stringstream` and parse that `std::stringstream` with `std::getline` to split on =. Ugly. probably better to use a state machine.

Comment: You are not respecting your format!!

Comment: OT:  You don't need `typedef struct` in C++.  Try using `struct Fighter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

typedef struct {
        std::string type;  
        int velocity;
        int attack;    
        int shield;    
        int cost;      
} Fighter;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string nomFichero;
    std::cout << "Filename:" << std::endl; 
    std::cin >> nomFichero;
    std::ifstream fich(nomFichero.c_str());
    std::string currentLine;
    std::vector<Fighter> allFighters;
    if (fich.is_open()) 
    {
        while (getline(fich, currentLine))
        {
            std::smatch match;
            std::regex re("(.+) \\(v=(\\d+), a=(\\d+), s=(\\d+), c=(\\d+)\\)$");
            int index = 0;
            Fighter f;
            while (std::regex_search (currentLine, match, re)) 
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < match.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (i == 1) f.type = match[i];
                    else if (i == 2) f.velocity = std::stoi(match[i]);
                    else if (i == 3) f.attack = std::stoi(match[i]);
                    else if (i == 4) f.shield = std::stoi(match[i]);
                    else if (i == 5) f.cost = std::stoi(match[i]);
                }
                currentLine = match.suffix().str();
                allFighters.push_back(f);
            }
        }
        fich.close();
        for (Fighter& f : allFighters) 
            std::cout << f.type << ", " << f.attack << ", " << f.shield << ", " << f.cost << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's my little solution using regexes, it can read multiple fighters in one file :

For example :

```
TIE-Fighter (v=250, a=75, s=30, c=45)
COOL-Fighter (v=400, a=60, s=90, c=55)
```

Will output :

```
TIE-Fighter, 75, 30, 45
COOL-Fighter, 60, 90, 55
```